# What does it mean by SQLState = 42000?

Tags: sql, jdbc, tibco

I am getting the following error when I try to start an integration in Tibco:

```
JDBC error reported: (SQLState = 42000) - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user '<user>'@'<server>' for table '<tablename>'
```

Is it because the user doesn't have SELECT query permission, or could it be another reason?

I'm asking here because the user has SELECT permission and still it throws this error.

Comment: Thanks man. i dont have access to google, thats y i am not able to search it. thanks for quoting this answer for me. really help full.

Comment: happy to help anytime :)